# Adding legends to a video made of figures

Tags: legending, video

To simplify the question, let's assume I am generating some figures using

```
graphics =
 Table[
  Plot[Sin[n  x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}],
  {n, 1, 5, 0.5}];
```

and convert the figures into a video

```
vid = FrameListVideo[graphics, FrameRate -> 2]
```

everything works fine but I need some legends on the side. However, when I add the legend,

```
graphics =
 Table[
  Plot[Sin[n  x], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, 
   PlotLegends -> ToString[n]],
  {n, 1, 5, 0.5}];
```

the FrameListVideo returns an error.

ListAnimate works but the output and the frame around the video is not ideal for export.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You could do `FrameListVideo[Rasterize/@graphics,FrameRate->2]` then it's just working with images, which you can get looking exactly how you want before converting to video.

Comment: Thanks a lot @N.J.Evans